# Using a continuity equation, how to find the velocity if a fluid if the density is known?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields

Let's say I know how a density of some fluid behaves, so

$$ \rho(\vec{x}, t)$$ and
$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

are known.

Is it possible to know the velocity of the fluid from the continuity equation?

$$ -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \vec{J} = \nabla \cdot \rho\vec{v}$$

Or if the general problem is too complex, what a bout the special case of a homogenous desity so

$$ \nabla \cdot \rho\vec{v} = \rho \nabla \cdot \vec{v} $$

And the continuity condition reads

$$ -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \rho \nabla \cdot \vec{v} $$

Also, a numerical solution would be just fine.